# Why isn't $\int_{\gamma} \frac{\overline{z}}{2} \,dz = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

There's a Corollary saying the following:

$\mathbf{Corollary:} \text{ Let U be an open connected and simply connected space of } \mathbb{C}, f:\text{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \text{ an analytic function and } \gamma:[a,b] \rightarrow \text{U a loop. Then, } \int_{\gamma} f = 0.$

$\text{I don't understand why I can't apply this Corollary to the following:}$

$\text{Loop is defined by } \gamma: [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \gamma(t)=e^{it} \text{ and } f:D(0,2) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z)=\frac{\overline{z}}{2}$.

$\text{Here, I think that D(0,2) is an open connected and simply connected set (given 2 points, there's a}$

$\text{segment that unites them), f is analytic and } \gamma \text{ is a loop, but } \int_{\gamma} f = 2\pi i.$

$\text{Thank you for your help in advance!}$

Comment: $$\text{Why did you type like this?}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(z)=\overline z/2$ is not analytic. Apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I think that Riemann deserves better…

Comment: Hmm soz. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Like Empy2 already said, $f(z)=\bar z/2$ is not holomorphic. You can see this instandly if you know, any function that explicitly depends on $\bar z$ is not holomorphic.

Using Wirtinger Derivates it is possible to reformulate the Cauchy-Riemann equations into the condition $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}=0$$

Even though the Wirtinger Derivates are NOT differentialquotients, you can still formally differentiate with respect to $\bar z$ and $z$.

Applying this to your example, you can acutally calculate
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial\bar z} \frac{\bar z}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\not=0$$

This idea instandly provides a reasoning why for example $\mathrm{Re}$ can not be holomorphic, since $\mathrm{Re(z)}=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar z)$.

Answer (score 1):

One can however use Schwarz function $\bar{z}=S(z)$ on $\gamma$ to evaluate the contour. Notice that on $\gamma$ the identity $z\bar{z}=2\Leftrightarrow \bar{z}=2/z$ holds, so instead one evaluates
$$\int_\gamma\frac{\bar{z}}{2}dz=\int_\gamma\frac1{z}dz=2\pi i.  $$